# Writing SQL query for bids

Tags: ansi-sql

[image]

How can I write a query for this? I'm not an expert to write this much of complex queries in SQL. I forgot to mention bid 3, 4 here.

Comment: What values you need in the 'checkin' and 'checkout' columns?
Try using a GROUP BY clause for the 'bid' column.

Comment: Why is the checkout of bid 6 aid 12 instead of 13?

Comment: Please give more information so that people can help you. What **rules** are used to form your sample result? If you "forgot to mention bid 3, 4" then edit your question to show them! As it stands, your question is so vague that any answer given will be purely a guess. Not to mention that you may get an answer that _looks_ right but doesn't really fit the requirement. If **you** don't understand the requirement well enough to explain it, how will you confirm whether a given answer is correct? Please fix your question, or it may as well be marked down, because currently it's meaningless!

Comment: -1: You've been asked to clarify your question, and not done so.

Answer (score 4):

Based on David's query, eliminating duplicate bids and restricting by check type.

```
SELECT
   a.bid, min(a.time) checkin, ISNULL(min(b.time), '') checkout
FROM
   myTable a
LEFT JOIN
   myTable b ON a.bid = b.bid
WHERE
   a.type = "Check In"
   AND
   b.type = "Check Out"
GROUP BY
   a.bid
ORDER BY
   a.time
```

Comment: Note, I'm assuming you want the first checkin and checkout, if there are duplicates. That seems to be what the result table implies.

Comment: Hi thank you.. but here also it repeats the rows because time is different event the date is same. But I want to display only one row for entire date. I tried to convert datetime to only date. But it is not working for me

Comment: I converted like this 
ORDER BY  ( (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a.datetime,111)))

But it is showing error

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the description of the error, can you show an example of the problematic results?

Comment: @Nagu: If you want to convert datetime to date, use the following: `CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DateCol AS float)) AS datetime)`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
   a.bid, a.time checkin, ISNULL(b.time, '') checkout
FROM
   myTable a
LEFT JOIN
   myTable b ON a.bid = b.bid AND b.type = 'Check Out'
WHERE
   a.type = 'Check In'
ORDER BY
   a.time
```

**EDIT**

In response to your comment, seeing as there are several records of the same `bid`, and you only want one record per `bid` in your output, you need to specify *which* records you want in your output. When there are more than one, how do you decide what value to pick? If you always want the earliest checkin and the latest checkout, you might do something like this:

```
SELECT
    a.bid,
    MIN(a.time) checkin,
    ISNULL((SELECT
              MAX(time)
           FROM
              myTable
           WHERE
              bid = a.bid
              AND type = 'Check Out'), '') checkout
FROM
    myTable a
WHERE
    a.type = 'Check In'
GROUP BY
    a.bid
```

If that's not exactly what you want; adjust the use of `MIN` and `MAX` to fit your needs.

Comment: Hi David thank you for your quick response. But when I try to execute the query I'm getting repeatative rows. But I need only 1 row per one day (Means datetime)

Comment: I think you're still missing the min/maxing of times and a group by a.bid to eliminate the cases like bid=6 having two check ins

Comment: @fd: did you write that before or after my edit? there is a group clause, now... @nagu: is this better? otherwise, fd might be onto something. if both do the trick equally well, fd's code looks cleaner.

Comment: Didn't you meant `IFNULL` instead of `ISNULL`?

Comment: `ISNULL` is the sql server equivalent of mysql's `IFNULL`. OP didn't specify environment.

Comment: @Nagu: If you want only one row per day, why does the sample result in your question have 3 rows for the same day?

Comment: @craig young: i'm thinking he probably means one result per `bid` *and* day. and i guess i haven't quite accounted for that in my edited query either, i've just grouped by `bid`

Comment: @David, yes quite possibly 1 per bid and day; but then which check/checkout does he want in each case? He really needs to fix up his question.

Answer (score 1):

This will find the minimum check in and check out times for each bid id.

```
select bid, 
(select min(time) from table b where a.bid = b.bid and type = "Check In") as CheckIn,
(select min(time) from table c where a.bid = c.bid and type = "Check Out") as CheckOut
from table c
group by c.bid
```

Comment: You can do the same without subqueries :)

Comment: Seems like a hidden RBAR, please read up on: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/

Comment: I cant be bothered to register to read the article, but I get the jist!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT 
    `bid`, 
    MAX(IF(`type` = 'Check In', `time`, NULL)) AS `CheckIn`, 
    MAX(IF(`type` = 'Check Out', `time`, NULL)) AS `CheckOut` 
FROM `yourtable` 
GROUP BY `bid`
```